# How to select column values and count the records through join in mvc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to get some values by join table1 and table2 and the same time I need to join table2 and table3 and count the records with same id.

I need this to be done in MVC and I am a beginner.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq

```
from x in Table_X
join y in Table_Y on X.YID equals Y.ID 
select new {ID = x.YID , Count = x.Count()}
```

for more information check [http://pgopishetty.blogspot.com/2016/04/examples-of-different-linq-queries-in-c.html](http://LINK)

Comment: how to group these count on Id

Comment: Group x by x. YID

Comment: ViewBag.count = db.Session_traineelist_feedback.GroupBy(x => x.session_id).Select(x => x.Count()).ToArray();

Comment: I used this query and its getting the value.But I also need to select the id.How do I do that?

Comment: In the select there is 2 fields one is called ID that contains the ID and second is the count

Comment: sorry,I  didnt get you.How do I rewrite the above query to get id and their count

Comment: The select query is (select new {ID = x.YID , Count = x.Count()}) 

It will return a table of Ids with the count of each ID and thus you could call them after filling them in a variable using a variable.Count and variable.ID

Comment: ViewBag.count = db.Session_traineelist_feedback.GroupBy(x => x.session_id).Select new{x => x.Count(),x=>x.session_id}.ToArray()

Comment: Is this what you meant?